# How to use Nuget in SharpDevelop?

Tags: nuget, sharpdevelop

I am newbie in SharpDevelop and want to download Nuget packages. But I couldn't find any information about this topic on google. How to get Nuget packages in SharpDevelop?

Comment: FYI SharpDevelop has been discontinued. https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/issues/799

Answer (score 0):

I have taken new `nuget.exe` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/install-nuget-client-tools), put it to `c:\test`, in cmd -> `cd c:\test` I then entered `nuget` to get all info, and tried then `nuget install Newtonsoft.Json -version 13.0.1` - getting "nuget argument can not be null or empty" - [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218156/15893581) helped - tried ONLY `nuget install Newtonsoft.Json` - result "nuget unable to find package" - [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66879071/15893581) helped - I created **nuget.config** file with such content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

and put it near my new nuget.exe previously loaded...
PROFIT: `nuget install Newtonsoft.Json` - RETURNED needed nuget package's dlls of Newtonsoft (JSON.NET)...
and through `(left-mouse-button in your SharpDevelop project) Referencies - AddReference -> .NET Assembly Browser -> Browse` -- you can choose necessary c:\test folder (in my case) and dll version in it and add it to your project...
the oldest version (4.0) is better choice for best compatibility with both OS with NET.Framework 4.0 and OS with NET.Framework later versions as well