# Create a nuget package with GeneratePackageOnBuild and version patching

Tags: msbuild, nuget, versioning, appveyor, nuspec

What I've been strugling with for some time:

I have a "traditional" (i.e. non-SDK) csproj file. I want to create a nuget package. That's easy but devil hides in the details and I end up in the following catch-22

1. I can manually call `nuget pack .\Foo.csproj`, with or without a nuspec file, but then I get [the dreaded NU5128](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60249952/1303323) error. The chosen answer suggests to simply ignore the error. I would happily do that, but after publishing the package locally, I noticed that the dependencies are not included. Though there is one dependency to JSON.net that I added for the sake of testing. The same error appears in AppVeyor if I configure my `yml` to create the package.

[image: Dependencies screenshot]

2. I can specify all the packaging related properties in the .csproj file by setting `GeneratePackageOnBuild` to true. It works and takes the dependencies right but then I can't patch the version like I could do with the [replacement tokens of nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens). The version defaults to `1.0.0.0` even if I change it in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` to `1.2.3.4`.

Notes

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14808085/1303323) suggests that nuspec and csproj configuration can coexist and they are merged. The question is from 2013 so I *guess* it's not referring to SDK projects. Unfortunately that's not the case for me.
- I tried adding a `<NuspecFile>` in the csproj but then it seems that replacement tokens don't work and I get the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47398907/1303323). Probably because this instructed nuget to run pack on the nuspec instead of running it on csproj and merge the nuspec. I can't know for sure though as setting the build verbosity to `Detailed` didn't help to understand what nuget pack tried to do.
- Getting the `AssemblyInformationalVersion` in msbuild and use it straight to the `<Version>` property [isn't as straightforward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49627234/1303323) as one might think and it also defeats the purpose as `$version$` is doing exactly that according to the documentation:

> AssemblyInformationalVersion if present, otherwise AssemblyVersion

Is there a way to really "merge" `.csproj` and `.nuspec` with `$version$` patching and  get the dependencies in the nuspec right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the best course of action was to convert the project to SDK format. It has several advantages. Less configuration, no need for `.nuspec` file, no need for `AssemblyInfo.cs` or `VersionInfo.cs` files, `.nupkg` dependencies are correct and AppVeyor can patch directly the `.csproj` file *if* it's an SDK project file.

Not a solution *per se* if one wants to keep the legacy format, but it gets you going with the CI/CD instead of having you fighting with tools.